# Q&A chat onebox failing

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

Currently, when attempting to onebox a question or answer, not only does the onebox not appear but often a delay is incurred before posting gave up with "timeout".

Is this a bug?

[image: Screenshot of message timing out]

Comment: Actually, now all chat oneboxing seems to be broken in the same manner. Not sure whether bug is completely unrelated to the Zalgo post, or whether me and my friends have broken the oneboxing process...

Comment: A case for [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) then?

Comment: The root cause seems to be that the system attempts to use regex for one-boxing.

Comment: It is not limited to chat.so, also reproduced on  chat.mse: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1034/shadows-sandbox and it doesn't require a Zalgo post ...

Comment: https, it's always https.

Comment: @ShadowWizard maybe propose to turn it off?

Comment: Most likely this is a result of chat not running https but all of SO and all links are https.  [I was able to post the links](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/37243586#37243586) but it does not one box.  I had to hit cancel after it timed out and then click on another message to get it to pop up.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Chat's https for me

Comment: There seem to be other performance problems today. Related? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296319/cant-load-questions-in-the-ios-app https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296318/155739

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Oh wow.  It is not auto redirecting for me.  I need to update my bookmark.  In that case ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies for this - it was unexpected downstream impact from rebaking `http://stackoverflow.com` links across the network (1.8 million of them) to `https://stackoverflow.com`.

I wrote up some details here: [The Stack Exchange API v2.2 is down / unstable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296318/the-stack-exchange-api-v2-2-is-down-unstable/296323#296323)

Comment: Confirmed fixed. Thanks!